# How to connect 3 TTL devices together?

Tags: serial

I have 3 devices that I need to connect together.  They are supposed to be connected via serial port at TTL not RS232.  It only uses 3 wires, TX, RX and GND.  How can I make them communicate with each other, can I just connect all TX wires together and RX wires together?

Answer (score 3):

Just connecting all TX wires together, and all RX wires together won't work - you'll have all units talking on one connection, and all listening on the other.

RS-232-like serial communication is designed for two-way communications between two devices.  Adding a third severely complicates matters.

If one device can be considered the master, and in control of the other two units, you can connect the TX line of the master directly to the RX lines of the two slaves.  You would need to ensure that the slaves will only speak when addressed by the master, and use a switch or mux to select which slave TX line is connected to the master's RX line.

Answer (score 2):

As Peter noted, you cannot just connect everything together.

If you are careful designing the protocol running over the serial ports, you could make a ring:

```
A[TX] -> B[RX]
B[TX] -> C[RX]
C[TX] -> A[RX]
```

the packets sent would need to include the destination node and each node would need to forward packets destined for a different node. For example, for A to send to C, the packet would go from A to B and B, seeing that the destination is not him, would forward the packet to C.

Answer (score 1):

A device can listen to only one transmission at a time, so the listener has a problem when both others are transmitting at the same time. If you can somehow avoid this, you can use three two-input AND ports:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN7xUf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you can arrange that only one node talks at a time, and it is no problem that this tlaking node hears (receives) itself, you can use one three-input AND:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fSA4w6.png)</sup>

Comment: Hmm! @Wouter van Ooijen. Surely it is a bunch of OR gates you were intending to use rather than the AND gates as the ANDs imply you only receive a transmission on an RX pin if BOTH of the other two TX's is indeed transmitting. And unless they are both sending identical signals at the same perfectly synchronised time then you will get garbage (pretty much a certainty in this case). Try OR gates instead!

Comment: @Rod: No. USARTs are active *low*.